# How to access object property with dynamic key in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

In my component `Product.tsx` I receive an object via API call that could look like this:

```
{
  title: "Product 1",
  status: "active",
  tax: true,
  variants: [
    {
      id: 1,
      sku: 'PRD1',
      price: 24.00,
      price_reduced: 19.95,
      size: 'M'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      sku: 'PRD2',
      price: 24.00,
      price_reduced: 19.95
      size: 'L'
    },
  ]
}
```

I then render each `variant` as a row in a table where each column displays the price, size etc. as editable input fields. `onChange` of each `input` triggers `updateVariant(variant.id, key, e);` where `key` is one of the keys of a `variant` and `e` is the input event.

`updateVariant` should update the value of a `variant` with the given `key` and looks like this:

```
  const updateVariant = (
    id: number,
    key: string,
    e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setProduct((prevState) => {
      const update = { ...prevState };
      const i = update.variants.findIndex((variant) => variant.id === id);
      const updatedVariant = update.variants[i];
      updatedVariant[key] = e.currentTarget.value;   // errors on this line
      update.variants[i] = udpatedVariant;
      return update;
    });
  };
```

It gives me  an error on `updatedVariant[key] = e.currentTarget.value;`:

```
Element implicitly has 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be
used to index type '{id: number, sku: string, ...}'. No index signature with a parameter
of type 'string' was found on type '{id: number, sku: string ...}'
```

I tried changing it to:
`updatedVariant[key as keyof typeof updatedVariant] = e.currentTarget.value;`
which gives me the error `type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'`

I am quite new to Typescript and completely lost how to make this work.

**EDIT:**
I got it to work temporarily with

```
updatedVariant[key as keyof typeof updatedVariant] = e.currentTarget.value as never;
```

But this can't be the right / clean solution to this?

Comment: try `updatedVariant[key] = e.currentTarget.value as number | string;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by declaring an interface like so:

```
interface Variant {
  [key: string]: string | number | string[];
}
```

and then

```
(updatedVariant as Variant)[key] = e.currentTarget.value;
```

My mistake was to think that `key` was missing a type or something when in fact I needed an interface for `updatedVariant`.